# Error getting Google Plus Profile when authenticating with Google ID Token

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-plus-signin

When I try getting The Google plus profile information using the following code,

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(Config::get('services.google.clientId'));
$client->setClientSecret(Config::get('services.google.clientSecret'));
$client->setRedirectUri(Config::get('services.google.redirectUri'));
$client->setScopes(['profile', 'login' ]);

$id_token = $this->request->input('idToken');


$token_data = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token)->getAttributes();

$googlePlus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$userProfile = $googlePlus->people->get('me');
```

I get the error saying

```
exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me: (403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.' in /home/bepolite/websites/goodies/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110
```

This code used to work before and I changed nothing on my end.

Also I am using the official google php api which I downloaded using composer

`"google/apiclient": "^1.1"`

Thanks In advance

Comment: As far as I can tell you are not using any authentication. The `idToken` looks like it [only cryptographically ensures](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_idtoken) that the token came from Google and is for the specific user. It is not in and of itself authentication credentials.

Comment: @abraham This is what google proposes for authentication with idToken https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_idtoken

Comment: _ID tokens allow authenticating a user securely without requiring a network call (in many cases), and **without granting the server access to request user information from the Google APIs.**_ Having an `idToken` does not grant you access to authenticate with Google 
APIs. It just validates that request to your server are from the specific Google user.

Comment: I think my question should be"How do I authenticate users  by using their  I'd token. I am building an android app that does Google authentication. I usually get users data by sending their id token to my server. It seems this is no longer possible. Please Any walkarounds? @abrsham